# Logo center in menu and both are center with responsive using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this `navbar`, menu elements are dispayed in left side but I need a menu with logo in center so I have no idea

```
 <body>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#" style="display:none;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&text=Logo" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&text=Logo" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Logo Nav by Start Bootstrap</h1>
                    <p>Note: You may need to adjust some CSS based on the size of your logo. The default logo size is 150x50 pixels.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

    </body>

.navbar-fixed-top .nav {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar>.container .navbar-brand{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}
```

I have been playing around with the `size` by giving a `max-width` and `max-height`, as well as auto, I have tried moving the logo out of the `navbar header` and even out of the `container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something

**[Fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/CkdFm12m87)**

**Css**:

```
.nav.navbar-nav{
   float:none;
  display:inline-flex;  
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand " href="#" style="display:none;">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&amp;text=Logo" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <div class="menu text-center">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&amp;text=Logo" alt="">
                    </a>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Logo Nav by Start Bootstrap</h1>
            <p>Note: You may need to adjust some CSS based on the size of your logo. The default logo size is 150x50 pixels.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```